# iphone development: getting EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) randomly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, exception, crash

Hello I sometimes have EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) crash but I am faced with it randomly. I do the same process again and again but sometimes it crashes sometimes not. I tested in iphone 5 ios 6.1.3 iphone 4 6.1.3 and iphone 4 5.1. I always get the error in iphone 4, 5.1. What could be the problem? Thanks

```
Incident Identifier: 77645DC3-B169-49F4-B8D6-DE3D2782F58C
CrashReporter Key:   615a00e36fcb3c727a4ebbdbefd0883de0d533ac
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         ClickPicInt [1217]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C3422BE2-0C66-4728-82D2-7B7DCFDEF05C/ClickPicInt.app/ClickPicInt
Identifier:      ClickPicInt
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-26 00:55:57.294 +0300
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B208)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x36cfd88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33114259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36d00a9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36cff915 ___forwarding___ + 301
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36c5a650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   UIKit                           0x34eebba1 -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 1089
6   UIKit                           0x34ed1f37 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 183
7   CoreFoundation                  0x36c5c1fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43
8   QuartzCore                      0x3236faa5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 217
9   QuartzCore                      0x3236f6bd CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 217
10  QuartzCore                      0x32373843 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 227
11  QuartzCore                      0x3237357f CA::Transaction::commit() + 315
12  QuartzCore                      0x3239b911 CA::Transaction::flush() + 45
13  QuartzCore                      0x3239b8e3 +[CATransaction flush] + 35
14  UIKit                           0x34edcfb1 _afterCACommitHandler + 53
15  CoreFoundation                  0x36cd1b1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
16  CoreFoundation                  0x36ccfd57 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 259
17  CoreFoundation                  0x36cd00b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 761
18  CoreFoundation                  0x36c534a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
19  CoreFoundation                  0x36c5336d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
20  GraphicsServices                0x34e1a439 GSEventRunModal + 137
21  UIKit                           0x34efccd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
22  ClickPicInt                     0x00098b63 main (main.m:16)
23  ClickPicInt                     0x00098080 start + 40


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3691332c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3328a208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33283298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x335dbf64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x335d9346 default_terminate() + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33114350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x335d93be safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x335d944a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x335da81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x331142a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x36c53506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x36c53366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x34e1a432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x34efccce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  ClickPicInt                     0x00098b5c main (main.m:16)
15  ClickPicInt                     0x00098078 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x369033a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37730ea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37730bc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36903004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x369031fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36cd13ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36cd0124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36c5349e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x36c53366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x31c46c9c RunWebThread(void*) + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3324b72e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3324b5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36903004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x369031fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36cd13ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36cd0124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36c5349e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x36c53366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x328a5bb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x328a5a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x3293958a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3324b72e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3324b5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36913570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x36cd563a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3324b72e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3324b5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  AQClient
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36903004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x369031fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36cd13ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36cd0124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36c5349e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x36c53366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   AudioToolbox                    0x3713eb28 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 116
7   AudioToolbox                    0x370c5c9c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3324b72e _pthread_start + 314
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3324b5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36913cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33245f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33245cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36913cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33245f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33245cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36913cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33245f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33245cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ef20d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fe94a64
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x335dca4a     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x0021e4a0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe94a58      lr: 0x3328a20f      pc: 0x3691332c
  cpsr: 0x08000010

Binary Images:
   0x96000 -   0x137fff +ClickPicInt armv7  <c6090589ff903baa8eb9df9ba6a63fdb> /var/mobile/Applications/C3422BE2-0C66-4728-82D2-7B7DCFDEF05C/ClickPicInt.app/ClickPicInt
0x2fe95000 - 0x2feb6fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30554000 - 0x305cdfff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x305ce000 - 0x30642fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x3077d000 - 0x30781fff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x30784000 - 0x307e7fff  IMCore armv7  <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x30867000 - 0x3087dfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x308fe000 - 0x308fffff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3099a000 - 0x30adffff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x30ae7000 - 0x30aebfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30b8a000 - 0x30ba4fff  CoreServicesInternal armv7  <cccdb5638b17398f8082542c1b3c8cf6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x30ba5000 - 0x30beafff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x30c21000 - 0x30ee2fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x30f19000 - 0x30ff1fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31257000 - 0x31263fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x31264000 - 0x31264fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x31299000 - 0x3129cfff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x312db000 - 0x312dbfff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x312f5000 - 0x31306fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x3132e000 - 0x3134bfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3134c000 - 0x31350fff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3154e000 - 0x315cdfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x31812000 - 0x3181bfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3181c000 - 0x3186dfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x318bb000 - 0x31904fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x31905000 - 0x3191efff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3192c000 - 0x3197afff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x31983000 - 0x31987fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <98fa4b090d693115809eb6529e9beb8b> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x31988000 - 0x3198efff  XPCObjects armv7  <dc568831fa5b3b22b673c62bc9d21d16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x31b32000 - 0x31b7bfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x31b9d000 - 0x3235cfff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3236a000 - 0x3245bfff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3245c000 - 0x32466fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x324ae000 - 0x32506fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32507000 - 0x325b4fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x325b5000 - 0x325f8fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <1e32693f0983309b83784500fe1f9128> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x326a3000 - 0x32759fff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3277b000 - 0x3278afff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x327cf000 - 0x327d2fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <97feb1ab69973d1d84dbf3f4eb0dd0ad> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x32885000 - 0x32889fff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3288a000 - 0x3288bfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x32895000 - 0x32a13fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x32a5d000 - 0x32a94fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32aa3000 - 0x32b4dfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x32b7d000 - 0x32b7ffff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x32b84000 - 0x32b90fff  Accounts armv7  <79f22009b1173e1e81f70fc5c0410119> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x32ba8000 - 0x32bb0fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x32bc2000 - 0x33106fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3310b000 - 0x331d1fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x331ee000 - 0x33211fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3323d000 - 0x332c9fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <50504d85a72b3857a1702a2084dca557> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3330d000 - 0x33310fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x333a4000 - 0x333c4fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x333c5000 - 0x333eafff  OpenCL armv7  <0a0ef4515cb9344ea59b4abb19c9eb7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x333f8000 - 0x33444fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33448000 - 0x33527fff  RawCamera armv7  <293f818ba6533dceae8b900b6ed3c887> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x3355d000 - 0x33563fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x335d4000 - 0x335d4fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x335d5000 - 0x335dcfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x335ef000 - 0x336ddfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x336f8000 - 0x337c8fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x337cb000 - 0x337cffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33807000 - 0x338defff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x338df000 - 0x338ecfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x33917000 - 0x33918fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x33d92000 - 0x33dcdfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33def000 - 0x33dfbfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x33e03000 - 0x33e3bfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x34aa6000 - 0x34aa7fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x34ab8000 - 0x34ae4fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x34ae5000 - 0x34aeafff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <4729a67709ba39e98750fdd6b36a3317> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x34af1000 - 0x34af6fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x34af8000 - 0x34c41fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34c42000 - 0x34c7efff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34ca9000 - 0x34cb5fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x34d3d000 - 0x34d7dfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34d7e000 - 0x34d94fff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x34e16000 - 0x34e20fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <147941e830dc3420b9c3ebc15954a1a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x34e21000 - 0x34e21fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x34eb2000 - 0x34ebdfff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34ecb000 - 0x3536dfff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x353b0000 - 0x353b3fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35414000 - 0x35429fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x35440000 - 0x35488fff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x355a3000 - 0x35749fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x35751000 - 0x35813fff  Celestial armv7  <19617260ee073e23b95e456d93930aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x358b8000 - 0x358cefff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x35a1b000 - 0x35a1bfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x35b0a000 - 0x35d37fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <c3098478486032c6aff336fa711c4fc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x35d3b000 - 0x35d3cfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x35d3d000 - 0x35d3ffff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35dd9000 - 0x35efefff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35f3c000 - 0x360f9fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x36105000 - 0x36124fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3616b000 - 0x361dbfff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x36201000 - 0x36201fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3622f000 - 0x36280fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3628c000 - 0x3628dfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x368cc000 - 0x36901fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36902000 - 0x36918fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x36925000 - 0x36934fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x36935000 - 0x36949fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <aa6476776bd733f08c8110afe00b6548> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3694a000 - 0x36959fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36a85000 - 0x36ac9fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36b14000 - 0x36b1efff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x36c17000 - 0x36c17fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x36c3d000 - 0x36c43fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x36c44000 - 0x36d5bfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x36dd4000 - 0x36ddafff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x36e22000 - 0x36e2afff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36e2b000 - 0x36e68fff  FTServices armv7  <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x36e80000 - 0x36e83fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x36f91000 - 0x36fcffff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x36ff4000 - 0x36ffbfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x37055000 - 0x37058fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x370c4000 - 0x372a8fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x372fc000 - 0x37338fff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x373ac000 - 0x373b1fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x373b2000 - 0x37438fff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x37439000 - 0x3744afff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3744b000 - 0x374f1fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x374fa000 - 0x374fefff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x374ff000 - 0x37523fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x37524000 - 0x3756efff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x37637000 - 0x37638fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x37639000 - 0x37683fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f581acd6df943b79adbe15bf9d93a9ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x37684000 - 0x3768afff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x3768b000 - 0x376e8fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x37724000 - 0x3773afff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x37993000 - 0x37999fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x37ba7000 - 0x37babfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
```

Comment: A memory management issue?

Comment: @H2CO3 I dont know. How can I check it?

Comment: I don't know either, you haven't posted any code. Double check your reference counts in first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175
-[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 1089
```

May be you should look at button selector methods ,all defined and connected properly